# Android automatic ripple effect is rectangle and not circle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am using the normal class of AppCompat but every clickable object that I click on him, show rect ripple and not circle;
I am using appcompat 22 and targetSDKVersion is 22.
For example:[image]

I don't know what making this look like that, Any idea?

Thanks

Haim.

Comment: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/ripples-part-2/

Comment: @pskink Thanks, but it should happen alone without writing code...

Comment: @pskink But he has defined it to each object. The ripple should be circle defaultly, but something is screwed...

Comment: @Haim127 did you override background of buttons?

Comment: @pengrad hmm look like not, but its not just it. CardView looks bad too (like a rect with rounded corners without elevation even I set the elevation) :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the hardwareAccelerated. If it is set to false it disable the ripple.